# Opensource hidden object game

Tags: windows, open-source

I am looking for some hidden object games whose code is open source.

Preferably in C++,C#...

I am making a hidden object game for my class project and I just want to see examples of how people usually implement levels and object lists. Apparently googling "hidden object game android code" & "open source hidden object games" doesn't do good either.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain what a "hidden object game" is? Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16512/open-source-hidden-object-game

Comment: @Chenmunka: The programming language is different though.

Comment: Related Meta discussion: [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/60)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Curiously enough, the text is almost identical. It would at least be courteous to indicate the original source, let alone helpful to explain in at least one of the two questions *what a "hidden object game" is supposed to be*.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that asking for "example code" is completely different from asking for "software for a specific purpose". The conclusion in the Meta question linked by @unor seems to support this. So *IMHO* both questions are off-topic here.